# Adobe acrobat reader 9 . No read out loud function

Tags: 14.04, adobe-reader

I need help in activating the read out loud function in Acrobat reader 9. I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit edition and I installed the missing 32 bit libraries but nothing works and the reading tab in preferences is grey in what regards the read out loud options, I see no drivers etc. What can I do to have the read out loud options activated for Linux. I read the answers to questions similar to mine but nothing helps thanks.
Edit: I have installed the libgnome-speech7 package but when I go to /var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread.postinst configure is see no file named acroread.postinst